# Convert JSON array to list of strings in spring using GSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, spring, gson

I have the following JSON

```
["2848","241"]
```

By using following jquery code

```
var list = [];
    $.each($("input[class='selected']:checked"), function(){
        list.push($(this).val());
    });
```

I am sending this data to my spring controller by using following in ajax post request.

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(list);
```

My spring controller is as follows

```
@RequestMapping(value="/myurl", method =  RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sampleMethod(@RequestBody String jsonData){
        Type dataType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
        List<String> myListObject = gson.fromJson(jsonData, dataType);
        System.out.println(myListObject.size());
        return "redirect:/someotherurl";
    }
```

I get 500 internal server error for some reason but no stack trace or errors on my console in browser. Please suggest what is missing.?

Comment: Check your server logs. You should see a stacktrace there.

Comment: nothing in my logs, i dont see any stack trace in my eclipse tomcat console either

Comment: There should always an error if you get an Internal Server Error. If you really can't find anything, set up a breakpoint and step through your `sampleMethod` code until you find the error.

Comment: Yes i did that, it always breaks here, List<String> myListObject = gson.fromJson(jsonData, dataType);....and I observed that my "jsonData" variable in the debugger was having some values like %5B% before my actual json string instead of [" , is it normal?

Comment: If it breaks there, shouldn't you see an error? Are the parameters of `fromJson` valid and what you'd expect them to be? This method could throw a `JsonParseException` or a `JsonSyntaxException`.

Comment: The parameters seem valid..fromJson(JsonString, ClassType)..the type i want to use is List<String> because the I am just providing a list of strings in Json Format like this .. ["value1","value2","value3"]...I also tried the other way like {["value1","value2"]}..didnt work..

Comment: Is that what you see when you debug that line, or just what you *suppose* is being passed in?

Comment: Thats what i see when I debug the line..I see my values in the jsonData variable..but the brackets and quotes are replaced by some % and numbers..

Comment: Is there any other way to send my list[] of values to my controller? Without using Json?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50821/discussion-between-nikhil-and-desertivy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by adding 
contentType: "application/json" to my ajax request. 
The server was not interpreting the json data properly.